# How to create 100 records in database while simulating 100 users using gatling?

Tags: gatling

While simulating the recorded scala file, the datas should fetch from csv file and insert into db.

For Eg:
If we simulate 100 users,Will it create 100 records in the database in case registration populates the database data ?

Thanks,
Mohanapriya

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to specify a "feeder" to supply data to your Gatling scenarios. Feeders can load data from a variety of sources, or may generate the data themselves. Gatling has standard feeders for several use cases, or you can write your own.

More details at http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/feeder.html.